# Code getting terminated without getting to the second user input

Tags: java

Code is getting terminated prematurely without taking the second user input.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws java.io.IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    char ch;                

    System.out.println("Press any key to throw a die and press Enter (or Q and Enter to quit)");

        ch = (char) System.in.read();
        if(ch == 'q'|| ch =='Q')
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
             dieFace = (int)(Math.random() * max) +1;
             System.out.println("You rolled a " + dieFace);
        }

        char pa;                

        System.out.println("Play Again? (Y or y) and Enter, any other key and Enter to Quit");

            pa = (char) System.in.read();
            if(pa == 'Y'|| pa =='y')
            {
                 dieFace = (int)(Math.random() * max) +1;

                 System.out.println("You rolled a " + dieFace);
            }
            else
            {
            System.exit(0);
            }
```

Comment: What is the last line printed to the console before the program exists?

Comment: Consider using a Scanner (https://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html) to read the user input.  That may be easier for you

Comment: The last line is the "Play Again" prompt from the System out. The code gets terminated after that and doesn't accept anymore user input.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't accept the second user input, is caused by that after first input, we need type `Enter` to end first input. That's the problem, `Enter` is also a input(with ASCII code 10).

We need try to read the `Enter` out, so that we can wait a new input. Just simply add a more read for `System.in` before second input.

```
System.out.println("Press any key to throw a die and press Enter (or Q and Enter to quit)");

ch = (char) System.in.read();
if(ch == 'q'|| ch =='Q')
{
    System.exit(0);
}
else
{
    dieFace = (int)(Math.random() * max) +1;
    System.out.println("You rolled a " + dieFace);
}

char pa;

System.out.println("Play Again? (Y or y) and Enter, any other key and Enter to Quit");

int enterKey = System.in.read();//this is the enter key char

pa = (char) System.in.read();
if(pa == 'Y'|| pa =='y')
{
    dieFace = (int)(Math.random() * max) +1;

    System.out.println("You rolled a " + dieFace);
}
else
{
    System.exit(0);
}
```

**Note:**`int enterKey = System.in.read();//this is the enter key char`, used to read the enter out.

**Advice:** The `java.util.Scanner` maybe more suitable here for you, take a look at [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)